# Is there a way to blur/highlight the text of a radio button?

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I have a form. When the user clicks "disable" I want to disable all the radio button and also blur/highlight the text so that it looks more "disabled".

How can I do that?

I tried adding a class to that element and using the blur function but it doesn't work. If editing the text CSS is impossible, is it possible to change the color of the button or put a border around the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is, the task looks quite simple. As long as you'd like to support old versions of Internet Explorer there is no true CSS way to blur the text, but chaging its color should be OK. Here is a quick example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#disable').on('click', function() {
        $('#myradio').attr('disabled', 'disabled').parent().addClass('disabled');
    });
})
```

Live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/ggzjF/

Comment: just what i wanted! weird, i tried something similar like adding a class but didnt work. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `blur` function doesn't actually (visually) blur anything. It removes focus from an element. It's hard to help you without any code, but this should get you going:

[How to blur text using CSS3](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-blurred-text-effect/#fbid=0mDjvjgZP21)

To disable the clicking of the radio button, set the `disabled` property.

```
<input type="radio" disabled>
```

Comment: i can disable things etc fine, i want to change "style" the text of that radio/checkbox so that when disabled, it looked "more disabled" if that makes sense. as for code, the thing is about 2k+ lines of javascript i dont think anyone wanna go through that..

Answer (score 1):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/RXs8B/1/

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="1" />
<label for="one" id="forRadion">First Item</label>
​<button id="blur">blur it</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Jquery

```
​$(function(){

    $("#blur").click(function()
                     {
                        $("#forRadion").css("color","#F00"); 
                         $("#radio").attr("disabled","true");//apply you own blur color
                     });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#disableBtn').on('click', function() {
        $('#formId input').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabledClass');
    });
})
```